# ASP.NET how to convert string to Date without forward slashes

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Just wondering how I can convert the following string into a datetime 111222, at the moment it is telling me that this is not a valid datetime value..

Comment: This is January 11th, 222, right? Or is it November 12 2022? Possibly December 22 2011?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method and supply the format your input is in.

Edit - added code:

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("111222", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

Comment: Tried the following         CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(this.fundsPayable);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(DateTime.ParseExact(this.fundsPayable, "YYMMDD", provider)); but getting error not valid date time this was with value provided of 111220